# How can I prevent transparent background-color blending?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1.0);
}

.inner {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">some text<span class="inner">other text</span></div>
```

My intention was that the `<span>` would have a light red color but instead I got red blended with the wrapper blue.
Is there any easy way to make this work as I expected?

Comment: Use a non-transparent color - you have millions to chose from....one must match the target color

Comment: You can keep another span which is absolutely placed behind this span. Give that a background of white.

Comment: If you don't want the colors to blend, why use rgba with an opacity? Your question doesn't seem to properly capture your issue.

Comment: So what effect are you going for...this doesn't make sense to me at the moment. I think you *might* be looking for a blend mode.

Comment: @Paulie_D I want the red span to be red with 0.5 opacity and to not blend with the blue

Comment: Well... **you can't**.  With opacity it will "blend" with something. I'm struggling to understand. There is no image in your code. Perhaps you need to show us what it is you are after.

Comment: What should the final result look like?

Comment: It will always blend, that's just how the transparency works. The first commenter here is right, just choose the target color and set opacity to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put the same `span` just behind the actual `span`, but with a white background-color. However, it's not a sustainable solution, and you should not use rgba color to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Keep another element that is a wrapper to your `span`. and give it background `white`.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #5555ff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

.inner {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display:block;
}

.fake{
    display:inline-block;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

some text

<div class="fake">
    <span class="inner">other text</span>
</div>

</div>
```

> Alternate solution:

You can give this color `#ff8080` to your `span` which does not have transparency. It will give the same effect.

Comment: What problem did the person marking negative saw here ? If its the OP then its diabolic. I saw he/she accepted none of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the use of `rgba(255,0,0,0.5);` you have an alpha option which causes semi transparency, your best bet is to simply use `rgb(255,0,0);` without the alpha or optionally set your alpha to 1 `rgba(255,0,0,1);`

Comment: Thanks for explaining how basic color work. but that was not the question.

Comment: For someone who understands how "basic colors work", your question doesn't even make sense. You're placing a semi-transparent red over a solid blue and expect a different result? What did you think would happen?

Comment: Well technically speaking it was a perfect answer from the explanation you have given in your question - want a better answer? write a better question.

Comment: "I want the red span to be red with 0.5 opacity and to not blend with the blue" <-- this literally makes absolutely no sense. If you put red see-through piece of cellophane over a blue background, you expect the red to not interact with the blue?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is probably to just use a color without opacity, other than that you could just wrap the highlight color with a white background wrapper...

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1.0);
}

.inner {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.inner-wrap {
 background-color: #FFF;    
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">some text<span class="inner-wrap"><span class="inner">other text</span></span></div>
```